# How do I make stop returning duplicate project_id and document_category_id being returned? JavaScript, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an async function where I am trying to get the list of documents via the year or organisation ID for each project.  My issue is that when the data is returned I am getting a list of duplicate IDs, `project_id` and `document_category_id`, where it should be just returning a single int.

What i've done is query the database and then looped through the query to extract the data needed and format it in such a way that is more easily readable.  I have a strong feeling it is the way that I am looping through the query and formatting the data, is what is causing the issue but I can't figure out where or what exactly.

code snippet:

```
// set org to SQL query or undefined if none passed
let orgID = req.query.orgID || undefined;
// get current year
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
// set year to SQL query or current year if none passed
let year = req.query.year || currentYear;

let queryResult;
try {
    queryResult = await documentService.getProjectDocumentsByYear(orgID, year);
} catch (error) {
    errorRoute.errorResponse(error, response);
    return;
}

// hold response data
let data = {}, sectorList = [];

// set sectors & project as an empty object
let sectors = {}, project = {};

// loop through results of SQL query
for (let item of queryResult) {
    // handle duplicate columns due to SQL joins query
    sectorsList.push(
        project = {
        project_id: item.project_id,
        project_name: item.project_name,
        documents: [
            {
                document_id: item.document_id,
                document_name: item.document_name,
                document_category_id: item.document_category_id,
                document_category_name: item.document_category_name,
                file_name: item.file_name
            }
        ]
    });
    
    // create new sector if none exists
    if (!sectors[item.category_name]) {
        sectors[item.category_name] = {
            category_id: item.category_id,
            category_name: item.category_name,
            projects: [],
        };
    }

    // add project to array of sectors
    sectors[item.category_name].projects.push(project);
}

// create an array of sectors
data.sectors = Object.values(sectors);

// add project docs to data object
data.projectDocuments = queryResult;

res.status(200).json({ success: try, data: sectorsList });
```

The result I get is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
         {
             "project_id": [
              10,
              10
              ],
             "project_name": "My Project",
             "documents": [
                 {
                     "document_id": 12345,
                     "document_name": "Some Random Name",
                     "document_category_id": [
                      1616,
                      1616
                      ],
                     "document_category_name": "External Clients",
                     "file_name": "Some Random Filename"
                 }
             ],
         },
            ]
}
```

what I should expect is an ID returned like in `document_id` :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
         {
             "project_id": 10,
             "project_name": "My Project",
             "documents": [
                 {
                     "document_id": 12345,
                     "document_name": "Some Random Name",
                     "document_category_id": 1616,
                     "document_category_name": "External Clients",
                     "file_name": "Some Random Filename"
                 }
             ],
         },
            ]
}
```